# How to document a member function from father class

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

How do I document a member function from a father class. There is a class A with a member function Afunc(), and I am gonna document class B extends A.
I do not overwrite Afunc() in B, yet I need the function Afunc() appear in my document, how do I do it?

I wrote

```
/**
 * description
 * @function Afunc
 * @memberOf A
 */
```

It works that appears Afunc in the document, yet there is a `<static>` tag at the start of the function name.
How do I solve it?
Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jsdoc 3.2.2 does what you want by default. In this example, the method `B.foo` will automatically be documented because `B` extends `A` and does not override `foo`:

```
/**
 * @class
 */
function A() {
}

/**
 * Foo the flerbl.
 * @param {Object} flerbl The flerbl.
 */
A.prototype.foo = function (flerbl) {
};

/**
 * @class
 * @extends A
 */
function B() {
}

B.prototype = new A();
```

Otherwise, you must use `#` in your `@memberof` tag to mark the object as an belonging to an *instance* of the class:

```
/**
 * description
 * @function Afunc
 * @memberof A#
 */
```

Comment: WOW~ It works after adding the '#' in my @memeberof tag. Really thank you very much!